# Where to discarded e-mails go in Lotus Notes 8.5?

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I have Lotus Notes 8.5. When an e-mail is discarded (no recipient was entered), where does it go? I need to retrieve an e-mail that I discarded.

Comment: What do you mean with "discarded"? Did you create a new draft email and closed it without saving it? Or did you create a new draft email and saved it as draft?

Answer (score 0):

It's gone. Until you save it somehow, it only exists in memory.